# Fill Dropdown with Fetched API Items

Tags: reactjs, api, dropdown

I've build an **react** app where I am fetching all the repositories from a user. I am trying to fill a **dropdown** with the returned items, but it does not work. I only get it to make a **dropdown** for every repository.

```
if (!repos || repos.length === 0) return <p>No repos, sorry</p>;
    return (
        <ul>
            <h2 className='list-head'>Available Public Repositories</h2>
            {repos.map((repo) => {
                return (
                        <select>
                        <option>{repo.name}</option>
                        <select/>

                );
            })}
        </ul>
```

How do I fill a **dropdown** with the returned data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have the `<select>` tag inside the `map` function. It is returning each element with a `<select>` tag.
Therefore all you need to do this take the `select` tags out of the `map`.

I also added a `key` and `value` for `<option>`. You can have it according to what you have in your `repos` data

```js
        <ul>
            <h2 className='list-head'>Available Public Repositories</h2>
             <select>
                {repos.map((repo) => {
                  return (<option key={repo.repoId} value={repo.name}>{repo.name}</option> );
                })}
             <select/>       
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!